# Exercise concerning the definition of the partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative

I found this practice problem for an exam, and I haven't been able to make a satisfactory answer. It goes like this:

Let $g(t)=f(t^2+1,t)$, where $f(x,y)$ is a differentiable function. If $f_y(1,0)=0$, then $g'(0)=0$. Is this true or false?

Because it is a practice problem, I checked the answer and it said it was true. I've tried using the fact that if $f_y(a,b)$ exists, that implies that there is a function $G$ such that $G'(b)=f_y(a,b)$ where $G(y)=f(a,y)$. But the $g$ that I was given is a function of $t$, so there can not be a constant parameter for $f$.

I'm completely clueless, and getting more confused the more I think. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: There actually was a typo. The function was $g(t)=f(t^2+1,t)$

Comment: Using the chain rule, what is $g^\prime(t)$? The crux of the matter is this: what is the differential of the mapping $t\mapsto (t^2,t)$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=g(t)=f(x,y)$ where $x=t^2$ and $y=t$.  Since $f(x,y)$ is differentiable,
by the Chain Rule we have

$g^\prime(t)=\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}\frac {dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac {dy}{dt}=f_{x}(x,y)\cdot 2t+f_{y}(x,y)\cdot 1=f_{x}(t^2,t)\cdot 2t+f_{y}(t^2,t)$.

Now substitute $t=0$.